# Nginx proxy manager proxy_pass not working as expected

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

im having troubles understanding whats wrong, because i lack knowledge and understanding.

I have domian for an application lets say its `dog.petrol.co` - it proxy passes location `/` to a local `VM` that runs `app1:8080`. No problem here. But i also have `app2:9600` that i want to be accessible on `dog.petrol.co/digit`

I tried to use the custom location, it didnt work, the web is not loading, and give 404, 502.

Then i also tried to use advanced tab. Now web loads but the assets like `/css/css.css` and `/images/img.jpeg` are still pointing to `dog.petrol.co/` and not to `dog.petrol.co/digit/`

This is my advanced tab:

```
location  /digit/ {
        rewrite ^/digit(/.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.333:9600/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
```

With this it loads, and keeps loading the page forever, but once i stop/cancel then it returns the HTML but the assets like i said, trying to pull from main domain no from sub path /digit/.

I can access them assets manually if i enter the url `dog.petrol.co/digit/images/...` but when page loads it points to `dog.petrol.co/images/...`